# Prevent AJAX cheating on a web game

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

## Context

I have a web game in JavaScript.

I send scores and achievements with AJAX during the game.

So anyone can view the source code, copy this request and cheat on my game.

## Questions

- Any idea of how prevent this?
- With a token from server (I never used this system)?

## Code

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
$.post('ajax/score.php', {pseudo: $pseudo, score: $score, achiev: $achiev},
    function(data) {
        $('#loader').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
    }
);
```

**[php](/questions/tagged/php):**

```
if (isset($_POST['pseudo']) &&
    isset($_POST['score']) && 
    isset($_POST['achiev'])) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Only get method can possible,but not in post method.you are using a post method,may be it will helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756591/prevent-direct-access-to-file-called-by-ajax-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the game is client side, there is no way to ensure that they do not "cheat". There are ways to make it more difficult.

- Have all calculations performed serverside, and send back tokens...this may not be possible/feasible for your game.
- Change the code served each time so that it will require more time to "decipher" all the requests.
- Obfuscate the code...this is only a deterrent.
- Have "tokens" sent during the game to see if the data matches (for example you can't win the racing game in 5 sec)...this too can be spoofed.

As long as the game is client side, it cannot be "secured".