# How to forbid direct URL access to a PHP file called via AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm making an AJAX call from example.com/js/script.js to example.com/inc/ajax.php and need to deny direct access to the PHP file if a user tries accessing it directly via their browser.

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756591/prevent-direct-access-to-file-called-by-ajax-function) suggests checking a HTTP header. The problem with that approach is headers can be easily spoofed.

How can check if an AJAX-called PHP file has been accessed directly and provide a 403 Forbidden response?

Comment: if you dont trust the header - you cant. the joy of stateless protocols.

Comment: If it's an AJAX call then it is coming from the clients browser, always. Java script executes on the client end.

Comment: Why would you bother? If your website's page can get the result, then the user *can always see* what the response is simply by looking at the network tag of their dev tools. Just keep it a normal URL. Instead, can you explain why you think this is even a sensible idea? (e.g. what is in that file that you don't want people to find, but do want to be XHRable? Because those two things are kind of mutually exclusive)

Comment: Route the request through your main application and deny all direct access to `/inc`? Use `include`?

Comment: +greg_diesel you really think i cant "fake" such a request to his ajax.php ? its just a get call with some headers.

Comment: you could set/remove a session variable  that your php script checks for the presence of?

Comment: Is this actually a security concern? Can you explain how? It might reveal deeper problems.

Comment: @Rufinus I think you misunderstood by comment.  My point is the request is always coming from the client.  Meaning the client will always be able to access that data.

Comment: If you're doing it right your ajax call should include some parameters, so that if the user just goes to ajax.php (no parameters) absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: @greg_diesel true, true. it seems he is trying to achieve some security by obscurity.... which never works.

Comment: I don't have a specific security concern in mind; instead, I was just interested if this was at all possible.

Comment: the "problem" with HTTP is, its stateless, and with all benefits it has, this is one of the downsides. each request is a request on its own... and doesnt now anything about other requests. (sessions are just a way to get around exactly that problem)

Comment: @WesleyMurch routing the request through my main application sounds an interesting idea. Any chance you could explain in a little more detail?

Comment: For example, making the request to index.php or whatever, checking the parameters, and including the appropriate file from `/inc` to output the response. I mean it really doesn't solve anything, but your concern is not particularly clear. I don't know why someone would end up making a direct request in their browser to one of your ajax handlers unless you are linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since each AJAX request is a normal browser request that happens in the background, it could be analyzed and reproduced with the developer-tools most browser provide.

The only thing i can think of is an one-time-token that you send with your ajax request that get validated and destroyed serverside. but even that could be tricked at some point.

Comment: Passing a token is a good idea, best alternative I've heard yet. Agreed it also can be spoofed

Comment: create a .htaccess in folder where ajax file is saved with below value 

    php_value auto_prepend_file check.php

auto_prepend_file specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. You can use it to include a "checker" script automatically.

and create check.php as you want:

    <?
    if( !@$_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] ){
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        exit;
    }
    ?>

This is just a way to avoid direct hit, and can be spoofed though with tools.