# WordPress Ajax Call -- WordPress User ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress based site, which I am new to. Basically, we are using a plugin to track "points" on the site, and I am using a call to get the user's wordpress ID for the games. However, the issue is that when I make an ajax call it returns 0 (aka not logged in) for the user ID, but when I visit the PHP page directly it gives me the actual user ID (example: 9). Here is the plugin function that I call in my PHP file:

```
function cp_currentUser() {

require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
return $current_user->ID;

}
```

and then here is my PHP file

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

require_once("wp-load.php");

echo cp_currentUser();

?>
```

and here is my cross-domain AJAX call

```
$.post('http://my.domain.xz/cp_getbalance.php', {}, function(result){

console.log(result);

});
```

If you go directly to the above URL in your browser while logged in it will give you the user id, but if I attempt it from the AJAX call I just get 0 no matter who I am logged in as.

Comment: This is correct behavior. When you are firing an AJAX Call from a different domain, Session is not present so wp_get_current_user() returns nothing. When you are hitting the link via browser, WP is able to identify the Session based on the Cookie.

Comment: can you try calling get method in ajax call?

Comment: How do you protect these scripts then? Just not showing the interface/scripts publicly is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong from my point of view.

You cannot get information from a cookie (client-side) on a piece of data that it processes on the server (server-side).

What you need to do is:

- Recover the current_user-> ID before the POST call in AJAX
- Send the retrieved ID in POST
- Process the data via server retrieved via $ _POST variable.

An example.

Your PHP file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

require_once("wp-load.php");

echo $_POST['user_id'];
```

Your cross-domain AJAX call:

```
<?php
require "wp-load.php";
global $current_user:
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
?>
var formData = {
    'user_id': '<?php echo $user_id; ?>'
};
//console.log(formData);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://my.domain.xz/cp_getbalance.php",
    type: "post",
    data: formData,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Having said that, in Wordpress the AJAX calls are done in a completely different way and I suggest you read this guide to better understand: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

I hope to be proved helpful

Comment: Let's say I forward my user_id to the "cp_getbalance.php". Do I really need to make a database request on "cp_getbalance.php" to check if the user_level is according to my needs? I guess there is a better (easier) way but I'm unable to find any good tutorial.

Comment: Forgive me, but then only the user_id what do you need if not to make calls to the database to extract certain data that you currently do not have? Explain to me what you need specifically, and maybe find a better solution.

Comment: I have the "editor" interface on the same custom page as the general user (Similar to what you see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aujNp92p0Uc). But I only want the editor to be able to do the changes. That's why I usually check the user level based on the user id. However, If I just POST the level to the ajax page, anyone could hijack that, right?

Comment: What I was looking for is this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362207/php-and-ajax-security-question

Comment: But as you can see, the concept is the same. Pick up the token and send it in post, don't do the opposite.
However what you were looking for was to make your script work with the parameters you requested

Comment: True, I needed both parts for the puzzle, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably always use `wp_die()`, whether in an Ajax callback or not. Even better, send information back with `wp_send_json()`  [options](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/).

```
require_once("wp-load.php");  //Please confirm your wp-load path
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $current_user->ID;
 wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you work with AJAX in WordPress is a bit wrong.

First of all you should add extend your function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cp_currentUser', 'cp_currentUser' );
function cp_currentUser() {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");

  echo $current_user->ID;

  wp_die();
}
```

Function `get_currentuserinfo()` deprecated ([Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)).

Second your Ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://my.domain.xz/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: { action: 'cp_currentUser' }
}).done( function( response ) {
   console.log( response );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `wp_get_current_user()`

```
require_once("wp-load.php");  //Please confirm your wp-load path
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $current_user->ID;
exit;
```

Comment: It is still returning 0 ;/. The script works when not called from ajax but just loading the php page directly.