# Accessing logged in user data in post request?

Tags: php, wordpress, slim

I have a whole site contained in a wordpress plugin. I'v been trying to get away from wordpress but I still depend on it to manager users. I need to access the data of the currently logged in user, specifically their ID.

When trying to access their data in certain places I kept getting the no user object:

```
object(WP_User)#1033 (7) {
  ["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1032 (0) {
  }
  ["ID"]=>
  int(0)
....
```

In the end, it seems to boil down to this. I'm trying to get this data in controllers called by my slim router:

```
$this->get( '/assignments', function(Request $req, Response $res, array $args ){
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
    $ch_user = wp_get_current_user();
    var_dump($ch_user);die();
}
```

and:

```
$this->post( '/userdata', function(Request $req, Response $res, array $args ){
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
    $ch_user = wp_get_current_user();
    var_dump($ch_user);die();
}
```

Both of these routes are in the same group, lines apart from each other.
The first one returns the correctly populated user object, and the second one returns the empty one with ID:0. The only difference between the two is that one is a get request, and one is a post request.

I am no word press expert, and I am just completely baffled by this.

edit:

I found similar issues left unresolved:

[WordPress Ajax Call -- WordPress User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144136/wordpress-ajax-call-wordpress-user-id)

[Wordpress REST API Retrurning Currnet User ID as 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355968/wordpress-rest-api-retrurning-currnet-user-id-as-0)

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I am assuming that the current user in your WordPress session was set using the standard WordPress login, e.g. http://aaa.bbb.ccc/wp-login.php.

In this case the current user credentials are received as cookies. The usual credential cookie is in $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE]. Can you verify that this is identical in both your endpoints by:

```
var_dump( $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE] )
```

One possibility is that this cookie is not received or damaged then the current user will be set to 0.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the logged in cookie is correct in the get request and null in the post request. The two operations are done in the same way in the same place to I can only think the problem lies with slim. I'm looking for anything to do with slim posts dropping cookies, but I can't seem to find a solution :/

Comment: The logged in cookie can be deleted(expired) directly by the server or indirectly by JavaScript code running in the client browser. You can check if the server is directly deleting(expiring) the logged in cookie by using the network tool of you browser and monitoring the cookies sent by the server. The server deletes a cookie by expiring it. On the Chrome network tool the cookies sent by the server are called Response Cookies.

Comment: If the cookies was deleted, wouldn't that log me out? The cookie is only missing during the request.

Comment: Yes, you would be logged out. To understand what is going on here I need more information. Is this site online? I may be able to get it using just the browser developer's tools.

Comment: It's not online, it's all local right now. What I'm saying is I'm not logged out, the cookie will still be there the next time I make a non-post request without me logging in again.

Comment: Yes, I understand but for some reason it is not sent (or removed by the server - possible but highly unlikely). I cannot help you further with the information given. It probably is easily solvable by monitoring the state of  cookies in your browser and the cookies sent/received by your browser. Good Luck.