# prevent direct access to jquery post url

Tags: php, jquery

i've a jquery script which `post/get` data to .php script. but i wanna prevent direct access to the php script. for example if the user look at the html source code,they will be able to access the php script directly by copying the url from the js file and i dont want that. how do i prevent users from doing that?? i want the user to use it via the html UI. i've google but found no link on this. however, i did notice that some popular websites are able to do that. how should i go about doing this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent direct access to a PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185483/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a simple redirect is what you're looking for here.

Add something like this to the top of your php file. This will prevent the page from being accessed if the proper post has not been made. Of course you'll have to change the post and redirect to content more relevant to your project.

```
if (!isset($_POST['data'])) {
    header('Location: your-redirect-location');
}
```

You may also be able to redirect based on the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable.

EDIT: I was going to explain this in a comment but it's too long. I should note that this is a simple solution. It will keep people from accidentally accessing your script. It's really difficult to create a 100% secure solution for your issue, and if somebody really wants to access it, they will be able to. If you don't have anything secure in the script in question, this will be fine. Otherwise, you'll have to look for an alternative.

Comment: tks jim u make it easy. i shall do that =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["post_var]))
{
//to the code you want to do when the post is made
}
else
{
//do what you want to do when the user views the post page
}
?>
```

Comment: hey tomi tks. i nv tho of this

Answer (score 1):

> how do i prevent users from doing that?

You can't - all you can do is *mitigate* the risk people can fiddle with your script. Making sure you have the right HTTP_REFERER and/or POST data are both useful in that regard: a "malicious" user would need more than pointing her browser to the URL.

More techniques can be used here:

- using session variables: you might not want users that are not logged in - if applicable - to use the URL.
- using a one-time challenge (token): you can place a value in the HTML page and have the JS code send this value along with the POST request. You store this value in the session when it is generated. Checking the POSTed token against the session token guarantees the user has at least "seen" the HTML page before submitting data - this can also be useful to prevent duplicate submissions.

However, remember that anything a browser can do, people can do it as well. All these techniques can prevent the curious from doing harm, but not the malicious.

All you can do is making sure nobody can really harm you, and in this regard, your Ajax URL is no different than any other URL of your site: if it's publicly reachable, it has to be secured using whatever technique you already use elsewhere - sessions, user rights, etc.

After all, why should you care that users use this URL not using a browser ? You might want to think of it in terms of an API call that, incidentally, your page happens to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to and has the same problems as a [cross site request forgery](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

To reduce your risk, you can check the request method, check the referrer, and check the origin if set.  The best way is to have a secret token that was generated on the server that the client transmits back in every request. Since you're dealing with friendly users who have access to your live code, they may be able to debug the script and find the value, but it would only be for one session and would be a real hassle.