# PHP include files (without directs access option) and load them with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, security

I'm loading content of about.php page with jQuery AJAX to my index.php  section like this:

```
$('.nav a[href="#about"]').on('click', function() {
  $('main').load('../../layout/about.php');
});
```

However in my about.php page I have this:

```
<?php

if( !defined('cute') ) {
 die();
}

?>
```

And index.php page this:

```
<?php

define('cute', TRUE);

?>
```

And while heading from index to about page, nothing loads. 
When I commenting out "php files' direct access block" code - about.php loads, however then I can access included PHP files directly.

Could you please help me to achieve direct access of included PHP files blocking and loading them by AJAX at the same time? Thank you!

Comment: googled `php prevent direct access but allow ajax` and found some results, eg [Prevent Direct Access To File Called By ajax Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756591/prevent-direct-access-to-file-called-by-ajax-function) and this [Prevent direct access to a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185483/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-page)

Comment: `defines` are limited to the page it was created on....use `COOKIE` or Session Variables.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you expect the PHP code from `about.php` to be inserted into `index.php` and then interpreted along with the main page's code.  That's not what's happening.  You're calling `about.php`, the server is running that file and returning the results (the HTML), and the HTML is being inserted into `index.php`.

So `index.php` is never seeing the define(), because `about.php` has already been processed; and `index.php` only sees the results of it.

Comment: Looks like so, because when i define CUTE in about.php - everything loads properly. So I'm going to use best answer from here [Prevent Direct Access To File Called By ajax Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756591/prevent-direct-access-to-file-called-by-ajax-function) even tho I don't know what is headers and it's spoofing :(

Comment: You could maybe set a Session variable in index.php, then call it (and unset it) in about.php

Answer (score 0):

At first: `index.php` and `about.php` are different scripts. That mean: `about.php` know nothing about `index.php` (if you need you can use [include](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php))

But as I understand your question right - you need to catch difference between ajax request and request from browser. Try to set second parameter `data` to [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

```
$('.nav a[href="#about"]').on('click', function() {
  $('main').load('../../layout/about.php', {request_type:"ajax"});
});
```

The clue is `{request_type:"ajax"}`. You can get it in your about.php via global post array:

```
if($_POST['request_type'] && $_POST['request_type'] === "ajax"){
   //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Is it better (more secure) than just covering code into:

    `if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) ) { DO STUFF } else { die() }` ?

Comment: headers can be spoofed

Comment: If you need more security - than prefer to use PHP SESSIONS (COOKIES) as @Forbs said.